# Read in .dat file with headers throughout

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read in a .dat file but it's comprised of chunks of non-columnular data with headers throughout.

[image: data opened in Excel]

I've tried reading it in in pandas:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pathname, item), delimiter='\t', skiprows = 2)
```

And it helpfully comes out like this:

```
       Cyclic Acquisition  Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2  24290-15 Y  Unnamed: 4  \
0          Stored at:          100      cycle         NaN         NaN   
1             Points:            2        NaN         NaN         NaN   
2    Ch 2 Displacement  Ch 2 Force       Time  Ch 2 Count         NaN   
3                   in         lbf          s    segments         NaN   
4         -0.036677472  -149.27879  19.976563         198         NaN   
5          0.031659406   149.65636  20.077148         199         NaN   
6   Cyclic Acquisition         NaN        NaN  24290-15 Y         NaN   
7          Stored at:          200      cycle         NaN         NaN   
8             Points:            2        NaN         NaN         NaN   
9    Ch 2 Displacement  Ch 2 Force       Time  Ch 2 Count         NaN   
10                  in         lbf          s    segments         NaN   
11        -0.036623772  -149.73801  39.975586         398         NaN   
12         0.031438459   149.48193  40.078125         399         NaN   
13  Cyclic Acquisition         NaN        NaN  24290-15 Y         NaN   
14         Stored at:          300      cycle         NaN         NaN
```

Do I need to resort to .genfromtext() or is there a panda-riffic way to accomplish this?

Comment: This, is some crazy-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a work-around. I needed the Displacement data pairs, as well as some data that was all divisible evenly by 100.

To get to the Displacement data, I first pretended 'Cyclic Acquisition' was a valid column name, coerced errors on the values forced to be numeric and forced the values included to be just the ones that worked out to numbers:

```
displacement = new_df['Cyclic Acquisition'][pd.to_numeric(new_df['Cyclic Acquisition'], errors='coerce').notnull()]


4        -0.036677472
5         0.031659406
11       -0.036623772
12        0.031438459
```

Then, because the chunks remaining were paired low and high values that needed to be operated on together, I selected every other value for the "low" values starting with the 0th value, and the same logic for the "high" values. I reset the index because my plan was to create a different DataFrame with the necessary info in it and I wanted it to keep values in appropriate relationship to each other.

```
displacement_low = displacement[::2].reset_index(drop = True)

0       -0.036677472
1       -0.036623772
    
displacement_high = displacement[1::2].reset_index(drop = True)

0       0.031659406
1       0.031438459
```

Then, to get the cycles, I followed the same basic principle to get that column down to just numbers, then I put the values into a list and used a list comprehension to require the divisibility, and switched it back to a Series.

```
cycles = new_df['Unnamed: 1'][pd.to_numeric(new_df['Unnamed: 1'], errors='coerce').notnull()].astype('float').tolist()

[100.0, 2.0, -149.27879, 149.65636, 200.0, 2.0, -149.73801, 149.48193...]


cycles = pd.Series([val for val in cycles if val%100 == 0])

0          100.0
1          200.0
...
```

I then created a new df with that data and named the columns as desired:

```
df = pd.concat([displacement_low, displacement_high, cycles], axis = 1)
df.columns = ['low', 'high', 'cycles']

        low      high  cycles
0 -0.036677  0.031659   100.0
1 -0.036624  0.031438   200.0
```